# How do I fix my while-loop and if conditionals in my guessAge(age) in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

Below is the description of an assignment I have. I have tried to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but every time I correctly input the number it will still say it's wrong and won't give me all six tries if I'm incorrect.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

**Description:**

> Write a function that will have an age as a parameter and will ask the user to guess that age.
>
> The user will have a maximum of 6 chances to guess (after the 6th try if it’s wrong let the user know he has exceeded the number of tries).
>
> The user may quit the game whenever he wants by writing (`QUIT`, `quit` or `Quit`) instead of an age and you must tell him an encouraging message like: (Don't give up just because things are hard!).
>
> If the user guesses the age correctly, tell him he did a great job and how many tries it took him to guess it.
>
> No matter what happens, at the end of the game thank the user for playing.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
def guessAge(age):
            
    guess = input("Guess the Age") #This counts as one try. 

    count = 1

    maxtries = 5
    
    quit = 'quit', 'QUIT', 'Quit' 

    while maxtries != 0:

        if guess == age:
            count += 1
            print("Great Job! It took you", count, "try/tries to guess the age. Thank you for playing!")  
            break 

        if guess != age:
            count += 1
            maxtries -= 1
            fail = input("Try again. Guess the Age")

            if fail == quit:
                print("Don't give up just because things are hard! Thank  you for playing!")        
            break
    print("You have exceeded the number of tries. Thank you for playing!")
```

Comment: You probably want to use `if-else`. `break` breaks out of the `while` loop.

Comment: You're starting your counter at 1 but only giving a max of 5. Counter should be 0 or max should be 6 (or max should be <=5). Also `age` isn't defined in your code. Are you passing it in? If so what happens when you **don't** pass it in? Does it fail or does it catch that error gracefully- food for thought

Comment: @JLPeyret that is incorrect, `input` will return an int if an int was entered.

Comment: Ah, so thats why there is rawinput and input.  I only ever use rawinput.  Always something to learn :).  Sorry, forgetting formatting is a frequent gotcha in these types of problems.

Comment: Question then: is input() doing an eval(raw_input()), basically?  Is it as risky as an eval can be wrt malicious user input?

Comment: I'm sorry, age is supposed to be a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
def guess_age(age):
    count = 0
    max_tries = 6
    quit = ('quit', 'QUIT', 'Quit')

    while True:
        guess = input("Try to guess the age -->")
        count += 1
        max_tries -= 1

        if guess in quit:
            print("Don't give up that easy! Thank you for playing!")
            break
        elif guess == age:
            print("Great Job! It took you", count, "try/tries to guess the age. Thank you for playing!")
            break
        elif guess != age:
            print("Sorry, incorrect!")

        if max_tries == 0:
            print("You have exceeded the number of tries. Thank you for playing!")
            break
```

The main mistake you made is you accidentally broke (`break`) out of your second if statement; which should have, by the way, just been a if-elif or if-else.

EDIT: Also note how I named the "max_tries" variable. This is really just a preference thing, but "max_tries" is much more readable than "maxtries". Also, some people, like myself, prefer "guess_age", over "guessAge".

Comment: Does this work for you, because it still won't print that I'm correct, say if I put in guess_age(15) and input 15, it will say I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm...I will go back and take a look at it then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like this:

```
while maxtries != 0:

    if guess == age:
        # correct
        print "you are right... yada yada"
        break # break out of while loop
    else:
        # incorrect
        print "you are wrong..."
        # no break here
```

In your program you use `break` in both cases, which breaks out of the while loop. I don't think that's what you mean to do.

Instead of two complementary `if`s I've used `if-else` which is good when you have complementary situations (right/wrong in your case). This may be better because I **know** it handles all situations without verifying the logic of the two `if`s is covering everything.

Also, to check for membership use `in`:

```
if fail in quit:
    break # break loop
```

If you don't want to worry about letter cases just lowercase what the user gave you:

```
if fail.lower() == "quit":
    break # break loop
```

Comment: It's still not stopping the code when I guess the answer correctly but it will give me six tries to guess. The 'quit' option doesn't work either. Is there something wrong with the if statement under the else? Am I even allowed to do that? I don't know how to implement the quit option.

Comment: @swimdawg12 see added details

Comment: It's still not working when I enter the correct age or "quit" to break from the loop.